# do we need continuity in $x$ to verify that $\mu_{t,x}(S) = 1$? question from Liggett - Continuous Time Markov Processes.

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability

Let $L$ is a probability generator:

[image]

We construct $T$ a semi-group using uniform approximations from $T_\epsilon = \exp(t L_{\epsilon})$. We would like to check that $T$ is indeed a probability semigroup:

[image]

Now the author makes an argument to prove property $(e)$ of definition 3.4:

[image]

I don't understand why one needs continuity of $\mu_{t,x}$ in both $t$ and $x$ variables.

---

Attempt: since $\sup_n \|g_n\|< \infty$, $\sup_n \|T(t) g_n\| <\infty $ and therefore
\begin{align}  \lim_n \alpha \int e^{-\alpha t} T(t)g_n \, dt &= \alpha \int e^{-\alpha t} \lim_n T(t)g_n \, dt \\
& = \alpha \int e^{-\alpha t} \lim_n\int g_n\, d \mu_{t,x} \, dt \\  
& = \alpha \int e^{-\alpha t} \int \lim_n g_n\, d \mu_{t,x} \, dt \\  
& = \alpha \int e^{-\alpha t} \int 1_S\, d \mu_{t,x} \, dt \\  
\end{align}

So since $\int 1_S\, d\mu_{t,x} \leq 1$ we conclude that $\int 1_S\, d\mu_{t,x} = 1 $ for every $t$. Why do we need continuity in $x$?

Comment: Could you elaborate how you conclude that $\int 1_S d\mu_{t,x}=1$?

Comment: well,  I don't know, Let $x(t ) =\int 1_S\, d\mu_{t,x}  $ $x(t) \leq 1$ is a continuous function of $t$ and $\int e ^{-t} x(t)\, dt = 1$ then it must be that $x(t) = 1$. Isn't it true? Or we could say that $\int e^{-t} (1 -x(t))\, dt  = 0$ implies that $e^{-t}(1 - x(t)) = 0$ a.s. That plus continuity yields $e^{-t}(1 - x(t)) = 0$ for every $t$ or equivalently $x(t) = 1$